# Referencing Docker container from server-side (from another container) AND from client-side (browser) with same URL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

I have two docker containers `frontend` and `data-service`.

`frontend` is using NextJS which is only relevant because NextJS has a method called `getInitialProps()` which can be run on the server, or can be run in the visitor's browser (I have no control over this).

In `getInitialProps()` I need to call an API to get the data for the page:

```js
fetch('http://data-service:3001/user/123').then(...
```

When this is called on the server the API returns fine because my frontend container has access to the internal docker network and therefor can reference the data-service using the hostname `http://data-service`.

When this is called on the client, however, it fails (obviously) because Docker is now exposed as `http://localhost` and I can't reference `http://data-service` anymore.

How can I configure Docker so that I can use 1 URL for both use cases. I would prefer not to have to figure out which environment I'm in in my NextJS code if possible.

If seeing my docker-compose is useful I have included it below:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  data-service:
    build: ./data-service
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./data-service:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      SDKKEY: "whatever"
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    environment:
      API_PORT: "3000"
      API_HOST: "http://catalog-service"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Did you consider adding a `data-service` alias in your `/etc/hosts` file for the 127.0.0.1 address ? If you are under windows the host file should be under C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc (please double check).

Comment: I have considered it, but it adds a dependency for others to set up the dev environment. It's not "plug and play" which is what I'm trying to get to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most elegant solution I've found is described in this post: [Docker-compose make 2 microservices (frontend+backend) communicate to each other with http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55922397/docker-compose-make-2-microservices-frontendbackend-communicate-to-each-other)

Example implementation:

In `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    URI: 'your-docker-uri:port'
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    URI: 'http://localhost:port'
  }
}
```

In `pages/index.js`:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const { serverRuntimeConfig, publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
const API_URI = serverRuntimeConfig.apiUrl || publicRuntimeConfig.apiUrl;

const Index = ({ json }) => <div>Index</div>;

Index.getInitialProps = async () => {
       ...
       const res = await fetch(`${API_URI}/endpoint`);
       ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer, I would've recommended you to use Runtime Configurations but I'm afraid [it's been deprecated](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration). Nevertheless, it's still possible to get the server runtime configurations "serverRuntimeConfig" value:

1. In `next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    apiUrl: process.env.NEXT_SERVER_API_URL || 'http://dockerbackend:8000'
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    apiUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://localhost:8000'
  }
}
```

2. In `@/config/index.ts`

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const config = getConfig();

let apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;
if (config) {
  apiUrl = config?.serverRuntimeConfig?.apiUrl
}

export {
  apiUrl
}
```

3. Import the config file wherever you need the API URL:

```
import { apiUrl } from '@/config'
```