# Networking a NextJS development server in docker

Tags: docker, next.js

I currently have a setup where I have a NextJS app in development mode in a docker-compose lets call frontend.

The backend is an expressjs app lets call backend.

I have an environment variable in my NextJS app that specifies the backend endpoint which I can either set as http://backend:3000 or http://localhost:3000. Depending on which endpoint I set, NextJS runs into an issue (client vs "server" side querying).

Is there a way I can access my backend from my host machine as well as frontend container using the same "url"?

Edited for clairty

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    frontend:
        image: node:18.14.2
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./Frontend:/app
            #      - /app/node_modules/
            - /app/.next/
        environment:
            - NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URI=http://backend:3000
            - NEXT_PUBLIC_CMS_URL=http://cms:1337
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh -c "npm install --silent && npm run dev"
    frontend-graphql:
        image: node:18.14.2
        volumes:
            - ./Frontend:/app
            # - /app/node_modules/
            - /app/.next/
        environment:
            - NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_BASE_URI=http://backend:3000
            - NEXT_PUBLIC_CMS_URL=http://cms:1337
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh -c "npm install --silent && npm run dev"
    backend:
        image: node:18.14.2
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        working_dir: /app
        volumes:
            - ./Backend:/app
        #      - /app/node_modules/
        command: sh -c "npm install && npm install -g ts-node && npm run dev"
    cms:
        image: node:18.14.2
        ports:
            - "1337:1337"
        working_dir: /app
        volumes:
            - ./CMS:/app
            - /app/node_modules/
        command: sh -c "npm install && npm install --platform=linux --arch=arm64v8 sharp && npm run dev"
```

Comment: "Is there a way I can make frontend and backend containers run on my computer's localhost" - yes, that's what `ports` does. Can you edit your question to make it clear?

Comment: Docker's `ports` exposes whatever you say on the host port at localhost. `3000:4000` means "expose port 4000 in the container as port 3000 on localhost."  You can expose multiple ports on your host machine at localhost. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @AndyRay NextJS queries to the backend on the "server" which would be on the NextJS container and on the "frontend" (client-side) which would be on my host mac device. The issue is, the "backend" with ports exposed would be localhost:3000 on my host mac device vs backend:3000 on the frontend "server" container. I would rather not have to have two backend URLs and want a single URL to access the backend from both the frontend client and frontend server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far was hacking around the host.docker.internal hostname.

As mentioned before, host.docker.internal can be accessed directly inside of a  docker container but as nextjs also needs to access the backend server from "outside" the container (in the browser) I mapped

```
127.0.0.1 to host.docker.internal
```

in /etc/hosts (tested on both mac and windows).

This allows the client-side requests to access http://host.docker.internal:3000, allowing you to use the same hostname as the "server-side-queries".

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094090/referencing-docker-container-from-server-side-from-another-container-and-from). It looks like we can easily set up server and public runtime configurations but I'm afraid it's been deprecated. Nevertheless, setting up server runtime configurations is still possible.

1. In `next.config.js`

```js
const nextConfig = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    apiUrl: process.env.NEXT_SERVER_API_URL || 'http://dockerbackend:8000'
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    apiUrl: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'http://localhost:8000'
  }
}
```

2. In `@/config/index.ts`

```js
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const config = getConfig();

let apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;
if (config) {
  apiUrl = config?.serverRuntimeConfig?.apiUrl
}

export {
  apiUrl
}
```

3. Import the config file wherever you need the API URL:

```js
import { apiUrl } from '@/config'
```